# SCSS (PHP) - Rule applied despite media query

Tags: css, sass

In my `layout.scss` I have the following code:

```scss
@media(max-width:1100px) {
  #wrap-nav .nav {@extends .block;} # Comes from generic scss file
}
```

in my main `styles.scss` I import that file, it looks like this:

```scss
@import "layout.scss";

#wrap-nav .nav {display:flex;}
```

I have no idea why but with a 1920px width I still see SCSS compiling this as

```
#wrap-nav .nav {
  display: block;
}
```

but it shouldn't be compiled without the media query, should it? Am I missing something here?

Comment: That is a run-time condition, not a compile-time condition.  The browser will check the max-width.  The SCCS compiler doesn't know anything about the screen width.

Comment: I am aware of this. However LESS compiles it as `@media(max-width:1100px){#wrap-nav .nav {display:block;}}`

Comment: Why do you have PHP in the title?

Comment: Just to indicate I use server-side compilation (not JavaScript)